# string.Split function in c# tab delimiter

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a function which reads a delimited file.

The delimiter is passed to the function by string argument. The problem is, when I pass the `"\t"` delimiter, it ends up like `"\\t"` and therefore, Split is unable to find this sequence.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
private void ReadFromFile(string filename, string delimiter)
{

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default);
        string[] firstLine = sr.ReadLine().Split(t.ToCharArray());

        .......
 }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I guess you are using something like

```
string sep = @"\t";
```

in this case sep will hold `\\t` double back slash

use `string sep = "\t"`

```
string content = "Hello\tWorld";
string sep = "\t";
string[] splitContent = content.Split(sep.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 12):

use single qutes for this like Split('\t'), this way you will be passing a char and not a string.

Answer (score 4):

pass parameter value as Decimal number of \t (tab) and convert to it Char.

```
 int delimeter =9;

 // 9  ==> \t 
 // 10 ==> \n
 // 13 ==> \r

 char _delimeter = Convert.ToChar(delimeter);

 string[] rowData = fileContent.Split(_delimeter);
```

Happy Programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in "\t" as the delimiter nothing will change it to "\t".  Something else is double escaping your tab.

```
    Blah("\t");
    private static void Blah(string s)
    {
        var chars = s.ToCharArray();
        Debug.Assert(chars.Length == 1);

        var parts = "blah\tblah\thello".Split(chars);            
        Debug.Assert(parts.Length == 3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do your split is replacing the TAB(\t) by a blank space on this way:

```
            if(linea.ToLower().Contains(@"\t"))
                linea = linea.Replace(@"\t", " ");
            retVal = linea.Trim().Split(' ')[1];
```

This code works for me.

Answer (score -5):

did you try : Environment.NewLine ?

Comment: I think you might have accidentally posted this answer here instead of on another question, because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question being asked.